# Google Analytics API Start and End Date

Tags: date, google-analytics

What time of day are the periods? For example, if I have 2013-06-02 for "start-date", does that start at the beginning of the day at 00:00? If I have 2014-01-03 for "end-date", does that mean it ends at the end of the day at 23:59?

If this is true, setting "start-date" and "end-date to the same value will mean it will only return data that has happened during that day?

To put in less words, are both the start and end dates inclusive or exclusive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's correct. the dates are inclusive. If you set both `start-date` and `end-date` to the same value you will get all data for that specific day.

Also worth noting that they respect the time zone you configured in your [View Settings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1010249?hl=en).